# Spark dataset unzip function

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a `Dataset[(A,B)]`. I'm looking for something like `unzip(Set[A,B]) => (Set[A], Set[B])`.  What are my options? I'm not finding anything in the Dataset API.  Do I need to drop down to RDDs and bring it back up?

This is caused by a join, are joins 'cheap' enough to do the join twice, just in reverse? Seems excessive since the two sets are there already.

Comment: Seems like they removed unzip from `RDD` also :(

Answer (score 2):

One solution, which should have been obvious I guess, is simply doing two steps of 

`val a = ds.map(_._1)
val b = ds.map(_._2)`